Weakly increasing array, find lowest index of each value quickly
Suppose I have a weakly increasing integer array of the form A=[0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3].  I want to find the lowest index of each value, getting an array of the form r=[0,2,5,6].  Also, it is possible that A will be something like [0,0,1,1,3,3], skipping one or more values like 2.  In this case, the result I need would be [0,2,4,4], like the index for a value which is missing (2) would be the same as the index for the next value that isn't missing (3).
In other words, I want to make an array r such that for each value 0 <= i <= A.last, we have A[r[i]] >= i and (r[i] == 0 or A[r[i]-1] < i).  I want a solution that is optimal, when A.length is much larger than A.last.
Originally I was just iterating through A from left to right and noting the first instance of a new number I see in r.  However, it started to become too expensive.  The array A is very long, like, for my application I don't explicitly have an array A, I just have a function outputting values, and I am searching across all the nonnegative integers, so it is like I have an implicit array A of length 2,147,483,648 (but for this question we can assume I explicitly have an array A, and I can probably convert the solution to my application).  This approach was originally taking only a few seconds so I didn't care to implement binary search, but now I am relying on this function more and it is becoming an issue.
I was next going to implement a repeated binary search, once for each index of r, but I am wondering if there is a way to have all these binary searches work together to complete the job even faster, and lower the complexity time maybe.
Also I know r[0] is always going to be 0 and is redundant but it does not matter to me very much to remove it.
I found this but it just does repeated binary search, and I am wondering if maybe there is a faster way.  function that returns the last met of each numbers in a sorted array

If you're consuming a continuous output stream then all you need to keep track of is the current index i and the most recently seen value v - whenever you observe a new value d you simply append i to r, d-v times. No need to collect and search an array of all values.
